# Session Value Mismatch in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

After login to the application, we are setting a value in a session variable in the `Login` Controller as below:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginInfo loginInfo, string returnUrl)
{
    //...
    HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyPID, 226617); //PersonId - 226617
}
```

But later when we try to get the same in another controller with below:

```
[HttpGet]        
public JsonResult GetDetails()
{
    int person = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionKeyPID));
}
```

I'm getting different value like `842151478` instead of having `226617`. Why I'm not getting same value. Can I get the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```cs
int person = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionKeyPID));
```

to

```cs
int person = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyPID));
```

Also you need to set the session key-value as a string, like:

```cs
// 226617 --> "226617"
HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyPID, "226617");
```